# Only show list option based on earlier form choice

Tags: php, html, list

Here's part of my form:

```
<label for="User">Select your account type:</label>
    <select name="usertype" for="usertype" id="usertype" required>
        <option value="1">Employee</option>
        <option value="2">Manager</option>
    </select>
<label for="User">Select the company you work for:</label>
    <select name="company" for="company" id="company" required>
        <?php
            include ('processors/generate-company-list.php');
        ?>
        <option value="NULL">I'll create my own company later</option>";
    </select>
```

I only want `<option value="NULL">I'll create my own company later</option>` to be available if they choose to be a manager earlier in the form. Is this possible?

Comment: Instead of null simply use `<option value="0">I'll create my own company later</option>";`

Comment: use `value=""` instead of `value="NULL"` and voilà!

Comment: I'm using null as this goes into an SQL database where I need NULL to be there for some later code. Edit, changed to value="".

Comment: use jquery or javascript

Comment: I'm not sure i've explained clearly, I only want the option to appear if they choose Manager as their account type.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function check(){
      var usertype=document.getElementById("usertype").value;
      if(usertype==2){
          document.getElementById("company").selectedIndex = "0";
        document.getElementById("company").disabled=true;

      }else{
        document.getElementById("company").disabled=false;

      }
    }
    </script>


        <label for="User">Select your account type:</label>
        <select name="usertype" for="usertype" id="usertype" required onchange='check();'>
            <option value="1">Employee</option>
            <option value="2">Manager</option>
        </select>
    <label for="User">Select the company you work for:</label>
        <select name="company" for="company" id="company" required>
            <?php
                include ('processors/generate-company-list.php');
            ?>
<option value="NULL">I'll create my own company later</option>";
              <option value="1"> listitem1 </option>";
              <option value="1"> listitem2</option>";


        </select>
```

I used javascript function to select 0 index whenever manager is selected and disabled second select box.

Comment: This works, but if you select manager, then select create own company, then select employee, create own company is still there.